# Find the closest date from string

Tags: ruby, datetime

I'm trying to convert strings like "Sep 11, Oct 31, Feb 28" into DateTime instances as part of a screen-scraper. Using DateTime.parse() works fine apart from when the data goes across years, and it naively (and probably correctly) returns a date in the current year.

For example the following test case.

```
test "dateA convert next year" do
  TimeService.stubs(:now).returns(Time.new(2013, 12, 30, 9, 30))
  assert_equal(Date.new(2014, 1, 2), Extraction.dateA("Jan 2"))
end
```

I updated my method to look at what would be date with year + 1, and return the closest to 'now' - this works fine. However it feels a bit ugly, and I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

```
def Extraction.dateA(content)
  return_value = DateTime.parse(content)
  next_year = return_value.change(:year => return_value.year + 1)
  now = TimeService.now.to_i
  if (next_year.to_i - now).abs < (return_value.to_i - now).abs then
    return_value = next_year
  end
  return_value
end
```

- TimeService.now is just a utility to return current time to help with stubbing.
- Excuse my ruby, I'm new to it.

Comment: An aside: Instead of writing and maintaining TimeService, if your stubbing is purely for tests, take a look at `timecop` gem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My day job is Java where such magic is not possible. TimeService.now is only 1 line though :)

Comment: as neil said, timecop is the better approach

Comment: adam, make sure you write a test case for the other direction: eg, dec 30 when the current date is jan 1.  i believe your current logic will miss that.  you need to try subtracting one from the year as well, and then find the closes among last year, current year, and next year (hah, neil beat me to it by 27 seconds...)

Comment: @Jonah I intentionally didn't include previous dates because this code is being used for forecast data which is only ever a few days in the future, but good spot though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works as intended, allowing for closest date in previous year as well:

```
module Extraction
  def Extraction.date_a(content)
    parsed_date = DateTime.parse(content)
    now = DateTime.now
    dates = [ parsed_date, parsed_date.next_year, parsed_date.prev_year ]
    dates.min_by { |d| ( d - now ).abs }
  end
end
```

A few points:

- Changed method name to `date_a`, just a Ruby convention that differs from Java.
- I made use of some built-in methods `next_year` and `prev_year` on DateTime
- I used a time difference metric and selected date with the minimal value of it from three candidate dates (this is what `min_by` does). This is simpler code than the conditional switching, especially with three dates to consider.

I forgot about `min_by` originally, I don't use it often, but it's a very good fit for this problem.

Note there is a pathological case - "29 Feb". If it appears correctly in text, by its nature it will define which year is valid, and it won't parse if current year is e.g. 2015.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know I keep defaulting to camelCase instead of ruby_style